# How plot data from VMD *.tml file with color coding guided by an Alphabetic Character

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot, gnuplot

I want generate a 2D plot like [this](http://goo.gl/qthaZm) from X,Y,Z data. I have example data that looks like this:

```
0 1 C
0 2 G
0 3 T
1 2 C
1 1 H
1 3 G
2 1 T
2 2 C
2 3 G
```

But the problem here is that Z is in the form of characters and I want specific color for each character like the one shown in [here](http://goo.gl/4WXIeF).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your problem setting the custom colormaps, or translating the characters to numbers?

Comment: Setting the custom colormaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you make an image out of it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# the input data is in a list of tuples (x, y, z)
# where x and y are coordinates in (0..n-1) and z a base type in TCAG
indata = [
    (0,1,'C'),
    (0,2,'G'),
    (0,3,'T'),
    (1,2,'C'),
    (1,1,'H'),
    (1,3,'G'),
    (2,1,'T'),
    (2,2,'C'),
    (2,3,'G') ]

# you want to have a color for each character:
colordict = {
    'C': (1, 1, 0, 1),
    'G': (0, 1, 0, 1),
    'A': (1, 0, 0, 1),
    'T': (0, 1, 1, 1),
    'H': (1, 0, .5, 1) }

# find the maximum positions in x and y
xmax = max(indata, key=lambda p: p[0])[0]
ymax = max(indata, key=lambda p: p[1])[1]

# create an image
img = np.zeros((ymax+1, xmax+1, 4))

# populate the image with the correct colors
for p in indata:
    img[p[1], p[0]] = colordict[p[2]]

# show the color map:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(img, aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
```

This gives:

[image]

Of course, you'll need to do something with the axes (labeling, scale, ticks, etc.) but depends on your needs. Now you have some colors defined by the characters in the coordinates you wanted to have them. (The colors are defined in RGBA, where A is opacity.)

---

BTW, if you like a bit more control, then `pcolor` or `pcolormesh`, latter being faster than former are worth having a look at. (`ìmshow` is still faster but more constrained.)

Comment: @Drv Thanks. But a little doubt before marking this as an answer. To make this code working I have to remove _ax._ from _ax.imshow_ in the last line of the code. I am newbie to both python and matplotlib, can u please explain why so ... 
Else it is working like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @p.in4matics: You do not need to remove the `ax` if you create the image as shown as an object (`ax` refers to the `Axes` instance containing the graph area). If you use, e.g., `pylab`, or if you have imported `from matplotlib.pyplot import *`, then you are using the stateful interface mimicking Matlab, and you just use `imshow`. See the section *Coding Styles* in http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html for a better explanation with examples. The recommendation is to use the object-oriented interface and thus I use it in my sample code.

Comment: @DrV Thank You for this. Can you please suggest me some good resources to learn matplotlib from the basics.

Comment: @p.in4matics: The official site is a good starting point: http://matplotlib.org/index.html. Look through the examples, they are well-written, while the API documentation is not necessarily the best starting point for learning (it is a great and well-documented reference once you know what you are looking for). There are numerous tutorials in the web, as well. Also, if you do not know how to do something, check the SO questions and answers, and then ask a new one, if you do not still understand how it works. There are even some main `matplotlib` developers following SO actively.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness a **gnuplot** script. You specify your RGB-colors (`0xrrggbb`) in a string as lookup table and (mis)use the `sum` function for creating a look-up function.

**Data:** `SO24595112.dat`

```
0 1 C
0 2 G
0 3 T
1 2 C
1 1 H
1 3 G
2 1 T
2 2 C
2 3 G
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### set colors via characters
reset

FILE = "SO24595112.dat"

set size ratio -1
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 1.0 border lc rgb "black"

myColors     = "C 0xff0000 G 0x00ff00 T 0x0000ff H 0xffff00"
myColor(col) = (_c=0, sum [_i=1:words(myColors)/2] (word(myColors,_i*2-1) eq strcol(col) ? _c=int(word(myColors,2*_i)) : 0), _c)

plot FILE u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):(myColor(3)):xtic(1):ytic(2) w boxxy lc rgb var 
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]